# Json/ajax code solution and some clarification

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax

I'm new to using AJAX and have to use it in one of my projects. I have to find a connection between a Java file and a JavaScript file using AJAX. How can I print hello out of a Java file using AJAX on JavaScript?

PS: I have already wired my HTML code to display whatever is on my JavaScript. I just simply need to print whatever is on my Java class file using AJAX in JavaScript. My current codes are displayed as follows:

JavaScript:

```
$.fn.getNEW = function() {

$.ajax({
    url: '/10.0UI/rest/documents1/loadDocuments1';
    dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
  $('#newcontent').html(data);
},
error: function() { 
    $('#newContent').html("error on ajax");
}}); };
```

java file:

```
@Path("/documents1")
public class newclass{
public static Map<String,String> param=null;
@GET
@Path("loadDocuments1")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public static void main(String[] args){
    new newclass().data();

}

public void data(){
    System.out.println("Hello through java");
}}
```

Comment: sysout only prints to your system console... you will need to return the value to whatever connected to your class

Comment: "Please provide code for both", "It's urgent" - this is really not how it works on any Q&A site populated by **volunteers**. Stack Overflow is not a clearing house for free labour. The idea is you show your problem in detail, someone renders assistance at their leisure, and then you make the final effort to integrate it.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: i didn't mean to offend anyone over here, its my first question on stack overflow and i've been struggling with the same problem from the past two days so just needed some help. im sorry for the way that i put it if it came across something unexpected or off-putting.

Answer (score 0):

i figured out what i was looking for, i had to create a json object in the java file in order to return values in the js file. following is the solution.

javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/10.0UI/rest/documents1/loadDocuments1';
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
  $('#newContent').html(data.msg);
},
error: function() { 
    $('#newContent').html("error on ajax");
}
});
```

java:

```
@Path("/documents1")
public class newclass{
@GET
@Path("loadDocuments1")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String data() throws JSONException {
    JSONObject hii = new JSONObject();
    hii.put("msg", "Hello from java (JSONObject method)");
    return hii.toString();  
}   
}
```